# How to test for existence of child node in XML?

Tags: xml, coldfusion

I am using ColdFusion 8. I am very new to XML.

I am trying to parse some XML.  I am looping through the response and getting the info that I need, for the most part.

The trouble appears when I loop through the ResponseNodes array and I try to get access CustomFields, if there are any.  CustomFields is only on some records, not all.

```
for (i = 1; i lte arrayLen(ResponseNodes); i++) {
    CustomFields = xmlParse(ResponseNodes[i].CustomFields.Field);
}
```

This is the error I get:

```
Element CUSTOMFIELDS.FIELD is undefined in a Java 
object of type class coldfusion.xml.XmlNodeMap referenced as ''
```

I see that the first two array elements are processed just fine, as they have CustomFields. The crash comes on the third element, which does NOT have a CustomeFields node.

How do I test for CustomFields?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can test for it's existence before parsing the XML with StructKeyExists()

```
for (i = 1; i lte arrayLen(ResponseNodes); i++) {
    if ( StructKeyExists( ResponseNodes[i], "CustomFields" ) {
        CustomFields = xmlParse(ResponseNodes[i].CustomFields.Field);
    }
}
```

Comment: I finished the code and got what I needed. I did, however, ask for more help/ideas on how to code the entire thing more efficiently.  Perhaps you could help with that question.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9710703/how-to-efficiently-test-and-parse-a-deep-value-in-xml