# How to efficiently test and parse a deep value in XML?

Tags: xml, coldfusion

I am using ColdFusion 8.

I am parsing an XML document and need to get at a single value that is buried deep in the document.  I am successfully parsing the document and getting the values I need, but it seems that there has to be a more efficient means to get to the same data.

I have NOT parsed much XML. Is having to test for the existence of keys this deep very typical in parsing XML or am I doing something wrong?  Is there a better way to code this?

```
// PARSE THE SOAP RESPONSE 
SoapResponse = xmlParse(httpResponse.fileContent);
// PUT THE RESPONSE NODES INTO AN ARRAY
ResponseNodes = xmlSearch(SoapResponse, "//*[ local-name() = 'OnlineBoothInformation' ]");

// LOOP THROUGH THE ARRAY AND GET EACH NODE
for (i = 1; i lte arrayLen(ResponseNodes); i++) {
  // CREATE NEW STRUCTURE TO HOLD BOOTH DATA
  BoothInfo  = structNew();

  // TEST FOR CUSTOM FIELDS TO FIND NEW EXHIBITOR
  BoothInfo.NewExhibitor = 0; // DEFAULT NEW EXHIBITOR
    if (structKeyExists(ResponseNodes[i], "CustomFields")) {
      CustomFields = xmlParse(ResponseNodes[i].CustomFields);
      for (j = 1; j lte arrayLen(CustomFields); j=j+1) {
        if (structKeyExists(ResponseNodes[i].CustomFields[j], "Field")) {
          Field = xmlParse(ResponseNodes[i].CustomFields[j].Field);
          for (k = 1; k lte arrayLen(Field); k=k+1) {
            if (ResponseNodes[i].CustomFields[j].Field[k].XmlAttributes.Name == "New Exhibitor") {
        BoothInfo.NewExhibitor = 1;
    }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

I am getting other values for the BoothInfo structure. They were MUCH easier to get at. I did not include them in this example.

UPDATE

I was able to rewrite the code and get at what I needed much more efficiently.

```
// NEW EXHIBITOR
BoothInfo.NewExhibitor = 0;
if (structKeyExists(ResponseNodes[i].CustomFields, "Field")) {
    Fields = ResponseNodes[i].CustomFields.Field;
    for (j = 1; j lte arrayLen(Fields); j++) {
        if (Fields[j].XmlAttributes.Name == "New Exhibitor") {
            BoothInfo.NewExhibitor = 1;
    break;
        }
}
}
```

Comment: I think you have misunderstood what "parsing" is. It's an operation you perform once on lexical XML document (a string containing angle brackets) to convert it to a tree of nodes as a data structure in memory. Once parsed, you can navigate the tree structure freely using DOM-like navigation methods, or you can search it declaratively using XPath or XQuery.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, I don't see why you're calling xmlParse over and over. You use that to convert a string to an XML nodeset, but you already have an XML nodeset.

You can use a more specific XPath specification for the nodes you want. Maybe something like, `//*[ local-name() = 'OnlineBoothInformation' ]/CustomFields/Field[@Name="New Exhibitor"]`. Then you can just check whether an empty array was returned. XPath is *really* expressive, but it takes some getting used to. Take care that while CF is generally not case-sensitive, XPath is. I copied the case from your CF, but that has to match the case in the XML in order to work.